# Where is the "stop seeding when target reached" option in uTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I remember uTorrent once had an option to stop seeding once "seeing goal was reached". Did it go away? I can't find it now (Windows, 2.2.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter 0 in the highlighted field to stop seeding.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I went over the settings 3 times and didn't find it :)

Answer (score 0):

On version `1.0.2` for Mac (and possibly the same for PC), it's located at the bottom of the "Bandwidth" tab of the Preferences dialog.